# retrieve a specific file and store

Tags: javascript, php, file

I have some php files which I am hosting on a web hosting site.I want to take a specific file from user's desktop and upload it to my server on click of a button.The user should not specify the file path and the file path is known to me.
For eg:

php code

```
copy("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\IMG_20141118_213032.jpg",
     "/home/u131954735/public_html/uploads/new.jpg");
```

where C:.... gives the path of the image file on my Desktop and /home/u13.. gives the path where I want to store the file on server as new.jpg.
But on running the above code gives :

> Warning: copy(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\IMG_20141118_213032.jpg): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/u131954735/public_html/upload.php

How to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't copy a file from user's desktop with the url (for security problems).

You can upload file sending it to server: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp